# Magento 2.3 Client Side less compilation static files not found

Tags: magento2, error, less, static-content-deploy

if I enable the Client side less compilation and flush the static file cache I will get 404 Errors for all files in the media and pub/static direction.
I'm using nginx.

If I compile the files manual with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Magento/backend en_US` it works but the *.less files are not compiled after I change something and reload the side.

Did anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: this is really hard to debug remotely. It's probably a configuration error